# Advice for a universal OpenGL ES application (iPhone & iPad)?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, opengl-es, universal

I am about to convert my iPhone OpenGL ES based app into a universal (iPhone + iPad) app, using iOS 4.2. What advice would you give me? Are there any notable pitfalls in doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you get the bounds rectangle for the screen dimensions rather than hardcoding the view size or anything based on window coordinates.

[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

Recognize that if your application wasn't fill-limited (i.e. the hardware can only fetch so many texels and display so many fragments per second) on the iPhone 3GS or earlier (640x480) screen.  That it very well may be fill limited on iPad or iPhone 4 (1024x768 or 960x640) screen size respectively.

Comment: The fill limitation is indeed something I had assumed would not be the case, but perhaps it is. If that happens, should I reduce my display link frame rate, or is there something smarter to do?

Comment: Fill limitations are a result of 1) window size and 2) scene complexity.  (2) is where you'll want to go on mobile devices because (1) means ugly scaling or partially filled screen.  For (2) reduce the sizes of textures, simplify shaders (es 2.0), cull unneeded geometry, and sometimes reducing the bit-depth of textures will help.